# Creating Mosaic with multiband layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, image-mosaic

I have twice scenes of landsat and I would like to create a mosaic with multiband layers with them. I have tried to do it with Qgis. However, the geoalgorithm which qgis has not able me to do it. Here is the message that I received before ran saga merge tool.

How can I do a physic mosaic with multiband raster layers using qgis?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool. In QGIS menu choose: Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Merge.
In dialog select checkbox "Layer stack". Input files - list of your bands. If you need just a mosaic of neighbor raster - don't check layer stack checkbox.

[image]

Comment: I edit my post because I think it wasn't clear. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is frustrating bit with QGIS, SAGA, etc. This is a very simple and straightforward technique but still not possible in QGIS. I figured that it'd take alot of time to make this happen via Python as well. So,

I implemented this using R and its possible to implement this via R with just a few lines of code. I came across 2 methods to achieve the solution to my problem.

*METHOD 1*

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
file1 = stack("inputFile2.tif")
file2 = stack("inputFile2.tif")
mer = merge(file1, file2)
writeRaster(mer,"outpath.tif",format='GTiff',type = 'Float32',overwrite=TRUE)
```

*METHOD 2*

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
file1 = stack("inputFile2.tif")
file2 = stack("inputFile2.tif")
mosaic(file1, file2, fun=mean, filename="outfile.tif")
```

This is relatively easy to implement.